# Can I run wire under a door saddle?

Tags: electrical, door-frame, extension-cord

Is it safe to run an extension cord under a door saddle to get power past the door? I have a window air conditioner that doesn’t have a nearby outlet, and the heavy-duty extension cord I currently use has to sit in front of a bathroom door, which is a tripping hazard, and looks crappy. I’d like to get that part out of sight. (Everything here is indoors, BTW.)

Given my space, it looks like I’m limited to some version of an extension cord -- new wiring just doesn’t appear to be feasible. The door frame is metal so there’s no trim to hide anything under. The walls are plaster, so opening/resealing them would be a major undertaking. The same is true for the hardwood flooring. It’s an apartment so I can’t get under the floor from below. On-wall wire channel is ugly, and difficult on plaster.

The only other thing I can think of is to pull up the doorway saddle in hopes of finding/making space underneath to run the cord, perhaps through a piece of conduit. But before I risk damaging the classic oak saddle, I’m hoping some wiser folks can tell me whether that makes any sense, and/or if there might be a better way. (I suppose there are those rubber cord covers, but I don’t know if they’re safe for AC power.)

Sorry for the long-winded post. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can use the rubber cord covers. It's not safe to run an extension cord through any part of the structure.

Comment: I would guess that the instructions for your air conditioner say that it must be plugged directly into a wall outlet without extension cord, no matter whether it's "heavy duty" or not.  And I'd check the specs on that "heavy duty" extension cord, as I've seen extension cords that are stated as "heavy duty", but are 16ga wire that can't even handle a full 15A.

Comment: Check with your local inspector but you may be allowed to run a proper wire outside the building. I ran a buried cable from one end of the house to the garage to add a plug.

Comment: TBF, it's a lot safer than tripping over it.